# How to Fetch complex values from Bean to Struts2 JSP page

Tags: jsp, struts2

The action class is returning `userList` which contains - `[String, BeanClassValues]`

In my jsp page,

```
<s:iterator value="userList" id="userList">
<tr>
<td>***NEED TO FETCH THE STRING VALUE of userList HERE</td> 
<td><div><s:property value="Name" /></div></td>
<td><div><s:property value="Age" /></div></td>
</tr>
```

How Name and age are from Bean class and thus can be accessed directly but how do I get the value of String in userList?

Comment: Sounds like a `Map<String,BeanClassValues>` would fit better your needs, though.

Comment: yes Andrea. Ill post the solution down as answer. I have set it in my action class itself as bean values, instead of manipulation in jsp

Comment: *userList which contains - [String, BeanClassValues]* - What? Is `userList` a `List`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `top` variable.

```jsp
<s:if test="top.getClass().isAssignableFrom(String.class)">
  <td><s:property/></td> 
</s:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the action class, I just had to set the values in the bean and add the bean in the userList.

```
 for(int i=0;i<listSize;i++)            
{
                    Object[] obj =(Object[])list.get(i);
                    count=(Long)obj[0];
                    hdr = (TABLEHdr)obj[1];
                    bean = new Bean();
                    bean.setCount(count);
                    bean.setName(hdr.getName());
                    bean.setAge(hdr.getAge());
                    userList.add(bean);
}
```

Then retrieving the values back in JSP was piece of cake.

```
<s:iterator value="userList" id="userList">
//In iterator
<tr> 
<td><div><s:property value='%{count}'  /></div></td> 
<td><div><s:property value='%{name}'  /></div></td>
<td><div><s:property value='%{age}'  /></div></td>
</tr>
```